# Why can't get the value of weekend in php

Tags: php

I don't know what are the errors of this code because it's suddenly not accurate the showing value to the user like this:
[image]

```
  $holidays = array();
        $query_holiday = "SELECT * FROM holiday_tbl";
         $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query_holiday);
         while($row_holiday = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
     array_push($row_holiday, $holidays);
  }


if(strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) > strtotime($row['due_date']))
{

$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$days = (strtotime($currentDate) - strtotime($row['due_date'])) / 86400;
$daysTemp = $days;
for($i=1;$i<$days;$i++)
{
    $currentDay = date("D", strtotime("+ ".$i." days"));
    $date_loop =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ ".$i." days"));
    if($currentDay == "Sun" || $currentDay == "Sat")
    {
        $daysTemp--;
    }
    else if(in_array($date_loop, $holidays))
    {
       $daysTemp--;
     }
}
echo $daysTemp;
}
```

Comment: in your `if` condition you use `$row` but its not define anywhere in your code.

Comment: `$row` might be `$row_holiday`

Comment: @Bhargav when i echo that row, it shows the due_date values from the database

Comment: @B.Desai where will I put that? ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation is rather convoluted. In these cases I find it's always better to start over and try to simplify the logic as much as possible. Here is my take on your problem:

```
function calculate_days_late($due_date = '', $holidays = array(), $current_date = 'today') {
    $days_late = 0;

    // Get the timestamps for due date and current date
    $current_date_ts = strtotime($current_date);
    $due_date_ts = strtotime($due_date);

    // If current date is not after due date then not late
    if ($current_date_ts <= $due_date_ts) {
        return $days_late;
    }

    $loop_date_ts = $current_date_ts;
    while ($loop_date_ts > $due_date_ts) {

        // If the looping date is not a weekend or holiday then count it
        if ( ! in_array(date('D', $loop_date_ts), array('Sat','Sun'))
            && ! in_array(date('Y-m-d', $loop_date_ts), $holidays)) {
            $days_late++;
        }

        $loop_date_ts = strtotime('-1 day', $loop_date_ts);
    }

    return $days_late;
}

// Test
echo '2017-09-05 = ' . calculate_days_late('2017-09-05', array(), '2017-09-05') . "\n";
echo '2017-09-06 = ' . calculate_days_late('2017-09-05', array(), '2017-09-06') . "\n";
echo '2017-09-07 = ' . calculate_days_late('2017-09-05', array(), '2017-09-07') . "\n";
echo '2017-09-08 = ' . calculate_days_late('2017-09-05', array(), '2017-09-08') . "\n";
echo '2017-09-09 = ' . calculate_days_late('2017-09-05', array(), '2017-09-09') . "\n";
echo '2017-09-10 = ' . calculate_days_late('2017-09-05', array(), '2017-09-10') . "\n";
echo '2017-09-11 = ' . calculate_days_late('2017-09-05', array(), '2017-09-11') . "\n";
echo '2017-09-12 = ' . calculate_days_late('2017-09-05', array(), '2017-09-12') . "\n";
echo '2017-09-13 = ' . calculate_days_late('2017-09-05', array(), '2017-09-13') . "\n";
```

Working example: https://eval.in/856018

Comment: Wow that's nice! Btw One question, Where will I put the query table holiday because the user will input the date holiday into the database?

Comment: FATAL ERROR: CANNOT REDECLARE CALCULATE_DAYS_LATE() (PREVIOUSLY DECLARED IN VIEW_BORROW.PHP:64) IN VIEW_BORROW.PHP ON LINE 64 

it shows up error

Comment: 1) If you want to use that function exactly as is then you need to query the holidays outside of the function and pass them in as the second parameter. 2) It sounds like you are including the same file multiple times? If so you can wrap the function in `if ( ! function_exists('calculate_days_late'))` to prevent the error. See: http://php.net/function_exists

Comment: Nice it's already gone the error but it doesn't show up the value, It doesn't display anything value. https://imgur.com/a/pDnZ4

Comment: Your original code used `echo` but my function simply returns the value. You will need to then `echo` the value or display it somehow depending on your application.

Comment: I already change all return into echo statement but nothing happens, and also inserting echo inside of your code to test if the echo will output but nothing happens https://imgur.com/a/6j7z4 please :(

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem might be but that's getting outside of the scope of this question/answer. You might consider marking this question answered and posting a new question with more details.

Comment: Ok Thank you then I will consider this question is answered by you!

Comment: echo $days_late;    
}
calculate_days_late(); // add param as per requirement

} , I add it in last part and only get this https://imgur.com/a/Ja3n3, I want to. And also how to connect due_date into my database that all row will calculate by your code